# ImportError: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block

Tags: python-3.x, linux, opencv, nvidia-jetson-nano, python

I tried to find out which version of some things i installed on my Jetson Nano.
So I wrote a few lines of code and run it in python3 by using a terminal.

And by doing the error shown in the picture occured.
In another topic I found out that you can avoid some errors by changing the order of your import.
That worked for me but obviously something does not work properly.

Maybe this could become a big problem if there is a program with many lines of code. I can't image that this error can always be fixed by changing the order of import.

Are there ways to prevent this error?

[ImportError: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9mrU.png)

Someone has a good advice and can help.

Thanks.
Chris

Answer (score 6):

Just add the library path in your bashrc file

`export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1:/$LD_PRELOAD`

Source bashrc and it should solve the problem on aarch64 devices

Comment: above command has a slight problem '/' after => export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1:$LD_PRELOAD

Answer (score 5):

if you preload the library it works correctly - like this

LD_PRELOAD=libgomp.so.1 python3 your_python_script

this is the link to bugzilla entry - apparently the issue is in glibc
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1722181